# How to read MusicXML file in FLASH CS4/AS3 in order to visually display the data

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, data-visualization

I want to create music Visualization in flash by reading the musicXML file.

Is there some sort of a class that reads it? or a help guide to understand the musicXML structure and how to use it in order to visualize its music?

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 1):

You use E4X (ECMAscript for XML) to read and parse MusicXML files in the same way that you use it to read and parse other XML files. To the best of my knowledge there is no additional class library available. Developers like Noteflight and Legato who are doing MusicXML in Flash find it better to sell services rather than ActionScript libraries.

There is lots of MusicXML information available at http://www.recordare.com/musicxml, including a tutorial at http://www.recordare.com/musicxml/tutorial. Creating music notation by computer is complex, so be prepared for a lot of work if that's what you want to do. If you have some other type of visualization in mind, that could be a lot easier. Being able to read music notation will be a big help; that's a level of knowledge that is assumed even in the MusicXML tutorial.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are only several methods, which will cover 80% of your XML-job:

```
attributes      An object containing attribute variables assigned to this element.
childNodes      An array containing all child nodes belonging to this node.
parentNode      This node's parent node.
firstChild      The first child in this element's childNodes,
                or childNodes[0]
lastChild       The last child in this elements childNodes,
                or childNodes[childNodes.length-1]
nextSibling     The node after this node in the parent's childNodes array.
previousSibling The node before this node in the parent's childNodes array.
```

The simple documentation is located here: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/